# Why does strict pragma fails for $a in Perl?

Tags: perl, pragma

The following code has unusual behaviour that I found to be odd. It's just part of a program that works otherwise.

```
 #!/usr/bin/perl -w

    use strict;

    $a = 0;
    $abc = 0;                                                                                       

 exit 0;
```

Due to `use strict` statement Perl insists that I modify the second declaration as:

`my $abc = 0;`

But it does not do so for `$a`! I tried this on multiple Linux distros and Perl versions. Could anyone explain the reason please?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [perldoc strict](http://perldoc.perl.org/strict.html#strict-vars)

> Because of their special use by sort(), the variables $a and $b are exempted from this check

Answer (score 0):

`$a` is used for sort() and as such doesn't require declaration.